# Creating Azure Storage Containers in a storage account with network rules, with Terraform

Tags: azure, networking, terraform, azure-storage

I am trying to write Terraform that will create an Azure Storage account and then a bunch of storage containers inside it. An important detail is that the storage account has network rules that restrict access to a specific address space. This was causing the container creation to fail.

I managed to get around this by using `azurerm_storage_account_network_rules`, depending on the containers so not to block their creation. Something like this:

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "this" {
  name                = local.storage_name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.this.name
  location            = var.location

  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_kind             = "StorageV2"
  is_hns_enabled           = true
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_container" "data" {
  for_each = toset(var.storage_containers)

  name                  = each.value
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.this.name
  container_access_type = "private"
}

# FIXME This order prevents destruction of infrastructure :(
resource "azurerm_storage_account_network_rules" "this" {
  storage_account_id   = azurerm_storage_account.this.id

  default_action = "Deny"
  bypass         = ["AzureServices"]

  virtual_network_subnet_ids = [
    # Some address space here...
  ]

  # NOTE The order here matters: We cannot create storage
  # containers once the network rules are locked down
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_storage_container.data
  ]
}
```

This works for creating the infrastructure, but when I try to `terraform destroy`, I get a 403 authentication error:

> Error: retrieving Container "data" (Account "XXX" / Resource Group "XXX"): containers.Client#GetProperties: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=403 Code="AuthorizationFailure" Message="This request is not authorized to perform this operation.\nRequestId:XXX\nTime:XXX"

This is with my Service Principal, which has `Contributor` and `User Access Administrator` roles on the same subscription. Interestingly, when I'm logged in to the Azure Portal as myself (with the `Owner` role), I can add and remove storage containers regardless of the network rules being present.

So, is there a way of setting the Terraform dependencies such that they can both be built and destroyed without hitting any authentication conflicts? Alternatively, would upgrading my SP's role to `Owner` (or adding another, more targeted role) solve the problem?

Comment: AIUI, `Contributor` + `User Access Administrator` is already pretty close to `Owner`. I think all that's missing is `Microsoft.Blueprint/blueprintAssignments/write`, `Microsoft.Blueprint/blueprintAssignments/delete` and `Microsoft.Compute/galleries/share/action`; none of which seem relevant. How is it that I am therefore free to perform these container actions in the Azure Portal?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is an expected behavior as you are setting up the `network rules` for the storage account to `deny` and only `bypassing` the `Azure Services`.

When you `deny` and `bypass Azure Services` the `Azure Services` like `Azure Portal's IP` gets the access to the storage account and you are able to delete it . But at the same time , when you use `terraform` to perform a destroy , then it denies because `your IP` which is being used by your machine to send `terraform` requests to Azure is `not bypassed`.

I tested your code like below with the same permissions:

[image]

[image]

***As a Solution you will have to add `ip rules` while creating the storage account to the add the `client_ip` like below :***

[image]

```
provider "azurerm" {
    features{}
  client_id="f6a2f33d-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"
  client_secret= "GZ67Q~xxxx~3N-qLT"
  tenant_id = "72f988bf-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-2d7cd011db47"
  subscription_id="948d4068-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"
}

locals {
  storage_name = "ansumantestsacc12"
  subnet_id_list = [
      "/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/xxxx/subnets/xxxx"
  ]
  my_ip = ["xx.xx.xx.xxx"] # IP used by me
}
variable "storage_containers" {
  default = [
      "test",
      "terraform"
  ]
}
data "azurerm_resource_group" "this" {
  name = "ansumantest"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "this" {
  name                = local.storage_name
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.this.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.this.location

  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_kind             = "StorageV2"
  is_hns_enabled           = true
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_container" "data" {
  for_each = toset(var.storage_containers)

  name                  = each.value
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.this.name
  container_access_type = "private"
}

# FIXED
resource "azurerm_storage_account_network_rules" "this" {
  storage_account_id   = azurerm_storage_account.this.id

  default_action = "Deny"
  bypass         = ["AzureServices"]
  ip_rules       = local.my_ip # need to set this to use terraform in our machine
  virtual_network_subnet_ids = local.subnet_id_list

  # NOTE The order here matters: We cannot create storage
  # containers once the network rules are locked down
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_storage_container.data
  ]
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: This gets trickier if the module is executed in CICD pipeline on publicly hosted runners or Microsoft hosted agents.