# Error 401: "Server failed to authenticate the request" while accesing data from Azure Synapse to ADLS Gens

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-synapse

I get the following error when trying to run the following simple command in Synapse Studio

```
 df = spark.read.load('abfss://storagefs1@storage1.dfs.core.windows.net/somefilepath.parquet', format='parquet')
```

It is important to mention :

1. I have already defined myself as Storage Blob Data Contributor on the storage
2. My colleague manages - he runs exactly the same Notebook and it works for him.
3. We compared the Assigned roles and they look similar
4. I have added my PC ip to the Networking page to exclude in firewall
5. If I open Azure Storage Explorer i can successfully access/edit the Azure storage with no issues

> An error occurred while calling o755.load. :
> java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: Operation failed: "Server failed
> to authenticate the request. Please refer to the information in the
> www-authenticate header.", 401, HEAD,
> https://storage1.dfs.core.windows.net/storagefs1/?upn=false&action=getAccessControl&timeout=90
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystem.checkException(AzureBlobFileSystem.java:1185)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystem.getFileStatus(AzureBlobFileSystem.java:504)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.isDirectory(FileSystem.java:1713)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSink$.hasMetadata(FileStreamSink.scala:47)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:377)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:332)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$3(DataFrameReader.scala:315)
> at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189) at
> org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:315)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:241)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at
> py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244) at
> py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357) at
> py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282) at
> py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
> at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79) at
> py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238) at
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) Caused by: Operation failed:
> "Server failed to authenticate the request. Please refer to the
> information in the www-authenticate header.", 401, HEAD,
> https://storage1.dfs.core.windows.net/storagefs1/?upn=false&action=getAccessControl&timeout=90
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.services.AbfsRestOperation.execute(AbfsRestOperation.java:207)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.services.AbfsClient.getAclStatus(AbfsClient.java:783)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.services.AbfsClient.getAclStatus(AbfsClient.java:765)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystemStore.getIsNamespaceEnabled(AzureBlobFileSystemStore.java:294)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystemStore.getFileStatus(AzureBlobFileSystemStore.java:785)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystem.getFileStatus(AzureBlobFileSystem.java:502)
> ... 19 more
>
> ---------- ~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py
> in call(self, *args) 1303 answer =
> self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
> -> 1304 return_value = get_return_value( 1305 answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
>
> /opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(a, *kw)
> 110 try:
> --> 111 return f(a, *kw) 112 except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
>
> ~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py
> in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name) 325 if
> answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
> --> 326 raise Py4JJavaError( 327 "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
>
> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o755.load. :
> java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: Operation failed: "Server failed
> to authenticate the request. Please refer to the information in the
> www-authenticate header.", 401, HEAD,
> https://storage1.dfs.core.windows.net/storagefs1/?upn=false&action=getAccessControl&timeout=90
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystem.checkException(AzureBlobFileSystem.java:1185)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystem.getFileStatus(AzureBlobFileSystem.java:504)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.isDirectory(FileSystem.java:1713)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSink$.hasMetadata(FileStreamSink.scala:47)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:377)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:332)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$3(DataFrameReader.scala:315)
> at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189) at
> org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:315)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:241)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at
> py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244) at
> py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357) at
> py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282) at
> py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
> at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79) at
> py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238) at
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) Caused by: Operation failed:
> "Server failed to authenticate the request. Please refer to the
> information in the www-authenticate header.", 401, HEAD,
> https://storage1.dfs.core.windows.net/storagefs1/?upn=false&action=getAccessControl&timeout=90
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.services.AbfsRestOperation.execute(AbfsRestOperation.java:207)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.services.AbfsClient.getAclStatus(AbfsClient.java:783)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.services.AbfsClient.getAclStatus(AbfsClient.java:765)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystemStore.getIsNamespaceEnabled(AzureBlobFileSystemStore.java:294)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystemStore.getFileStatus(AzureBlobFileSystemStore.java:785)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystem.getFileStatus(AzureBlobFileSystem.java:502)
> ... 19 more

where can be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

•   You are getting this error because, you don’t have **‘Storage Blob Data Contributor’ role on the storage account** as well as the **user id through which you are executing this command isn’t assigned as a user to the Synapse workspace or as a Spark admin role**.

•   Please find the below snapshot of the below command execution in my Azure Synapse workspace and check the output for the same: -

[image: Azure Synapse execution]

Command : -
df=spark.read.load('abfss://storagefs1@storage1.dfs.core.windows.net/somefilepath.parquet', format='parquet')

`The error I am getting after executing the above command is as follows and it is because, I am not assigned the ‘Storage Blob Data Contributor’ role for my User ID, thus since I do not have the privileges to assign roles to my user ID, I cannot assign the same and hence the error else I am able to execute the command successfully`.

Error : - ***An error occurred while calling o740.load.
: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: Operation failed: "This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.", 403, HEAD***

In your scenario, the **access to the Azure DataLake Gen 2 cannot be verified as you do not have ‘Contributor’ role assigned in Azure role assignments for your user ID as well as you might not have also have the ‘Admin’ role set in the Synapse workspace due to which you may be encountering the error 401**.

[image: Azure Synapse Admin]

For more detailed information, kindly refer the below link: -

***https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/70324***

Comment: thanks for the respond. If you mean "Storage Blob Data Contributor" in the Storage account - I already did that. Your last paragraph is not so clear please. "In your scenario, the access to the ..." - can you please Edit and type what roles exactly should i have and where?
We think we did all needed

Comment: You need to have a 'Contributor' role assigned to your Azure AD user ID under Azure role assignments, i.e., there are two roles in Azure, an Azure role assignment for managing resources in Azure and the other one is Azure AD role assignment for managing tasks related to identity and access management. Thus, check if your ID has the Azure role 'Contributor' assigned to your ID. If not, ensure that, it is and then try again.

Comment: I have Storage Blob Contributer on the storage. I have Contributer on the Synapse workspace. But it still doesn't work

Comment: You need to have 'Contributor' Azure role on the concerned Azure tenant/subscription. Please check that.

Comment: i have it already. but still not working

Comment: Please check the storage account firewall rules once. Ensure that you set network rule of storage account to deny and bypass the Azure service, for which purpose, I suggest you add a client IP while creating the storage account so that Azure Portal's IP can access the storage account. Kindly refer this thread for more information: - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71022815/creating-azure-storage-containers-in-a-storage-account-with-network-rules-with