# How to determine client_id and permissions from azure OAuth token

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am having an issue (403 error to storage container) and I would like to confirm that a token corresponds to a managed identity client_id

Terraform obtains a token with this HTTP request within an Azure VM assigned and identity with client_id=***

The request is

```
169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&client_id=***&....
```

Should the client_id of the VM assigned identity be included as a property in the OAuth token returned from the above URL?  It is not in the sub or oid properties.  If not how can I determine what permissions will work with this token, and to what client_id it belongs to?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/how-to-use-vm-token)

> If your VM has ***Multiple user-assigned managed identities*** Then client ID is `required` otherwise it is an optional parameter

when I tried to reproduce to get access token HTTP with client ID i am getting result successfully like below:

```
GET 'http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=https://management.azure.com/' HTTP/1.1 Metadata: true
```

[image]

To resolve this error *403 error to storage container* try to set ***network rule of storage account to deny.*** When you denied the request the bypassing azure service You must ***add a client IP*** while creating the storage account as shown below so that Azure Portal's IP can access the storage account.

[image]

You can make use of AZ CLI command to deny the traffic after all of the provisions are finished.

```cs
az storage account update --name storage_account_name --resource-group reource_group_name --default-action 'Deny' --bypass 'AzureServices', 'Logging', 'Metrics'
```

Please refer this similar [So thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71022815/creating-azure-storage-containers-in-a-storage-account-with-network-rules-with) by ***Ansuman Bal***