# Connect to storage account with firewalls enabled from SQL Server in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-synapse

I have a storage account with firewall settings enabled (restricted access from only certain IPs and VNets). I need to access this storage account from Az Dedicated SQL Pool residing inside a SQL server. For this, I am using the external table concept. All works well when the storage account firewall is disabled. However, when I enable the firewall, I am not able to access data as the SQL Server does not belong to any VNet that can be whitelisted at the storage account. I do not want to remove the firewall of the storage account for security reasons. How can data access be ensured in this case?

PS: I also tried with the resource instance rules at the SA. This will not work in my case, as the SQL Server and Storage Account reside in different tenants.

```
Msg 105019, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
External file access failed due to internal error: 'Error occurred while accessing HDFS: Java exception raised on call to HdfsBridge_IsDirExist. Java exception message:
HdfsBridge::isDirExist - Unexpected error encountered checking whether directory exists or not: AbfsRestOperationException: Operation failed: "This request is not authorized to perform this operation.", 403, HEAD, https://xxx.dfs.core.windows.net/xxx/xxx.csv?upn=false&action=getStatus&timeout=90'
```

This is the error when the firewall is enabled. Without the firewall, I am able to see the data.

Comment: Are you getting any error while trying to access the storage account (files)? Please include the query that you tried to create external table and the error message (If any)

Comment: @Subha_26 why cross tenant? That’s an unusual scenario. There is a way to securely bypass the firewall with the SQL Server MSI but that won’t work cross-tenant. You should probably add a step which copies the files to your tenant first.

Comment: @GregGalloway Its a company policy to not enable physical data flow across tenants. This is the reason behind going with external table concept, where the data is only a mere reflection of physical data.

Answer (score 0):

•   I would suggest you to please ensure that you ***check/enable the below option in the snapshot while configuring specific resource instances for having access to the storage account***: -

```
Allow Azure services on the trusted services list to access this storage account.
```

[image: Storage account firewall]

Also, **`select the specific resource instance that will have access to your storage account, i.e., your configured ‘Azure SQL Server’ on which your database is hosted and want to connect to. Since, communication between an Azure SQL Server and a storage account traverses through the Azure backbone network, which is secure, encrypted on both the sides and is deserted from the rest of the public internet, it is included in the list of trusted sources for connectivity purposes`**.

•   Thus, would suggest you **configure the same but also configure the access to this storage account through a system assigned managed identity for the Azure SQL Database server as only then the access based on it would be granted access as Azure considers it safe and by design, it is necessary**.

Kindly refer the below link for more detailed clarification on this: -

***https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security?tabs=azure-portal#trusted-access-based-on-a-managed-identity***

`To configure a system managed assigned identity to an Azure SQL DB Server, kindly follow the below link`: -

***https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-azure-ad-user-assigned-managed-identity?view=azuresql#set-managed-identities-in-the-azure-portal***

Comment: Please note that I have my SQL server and storage account in different tenants. In this case, I will not be able to assign the system assigned managed identity of SQL server access to Storage Account as Blob Data Contributor. This is the issue.

Comment: Then, I would suggest you to please refer to this SO community thread for more details regarding this, may be it will be of help to you : - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71022815/creating-azure-storage-containers-in-a-storage-account-with-network-rules-with

Comment: Not much help there. I am unable to figure out what else needs to be done other than creating a private endpoint to bypass the firewall

Comment: I think, the solution stated in my answer then is the only thing that can work. Try to convince the owner/facilitator of the other subscription to allow this.

Answer (score 0):

**To connect storage account with firewalls enabled from SQL Server in Azure**

We must use the ABFSS driver and Managed Service Identity Credential that connects to a Secured Storage account with Polybase.

1. As you have standalone dedicated SQL pool (formerly SQL DW) create the Managed Service Identity for it.

```
Connect-AzAccount  
Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId your-subscriptionId  
Set-AzSqlServer -ResourceGroupName your-server-resourceGroup -ServerName your-servername -AssignIdentity
```

[image]

2. > You must first upgrade to general-purpose v2 if you currently have a general-purpose v1 or Azure Blob Storage account.

Under **Access Control (IAM)** on your storage account. Give your SQL Database server the RBAC role of **Storage Blob Data Contributor**.
[image]

3. To connect with secured Azure Storage account.

```sql
#create master key
CREATE MASTER KEY [ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'somepassword'];

#create scoped credentials using managed identity created un first step
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL msi_cred WITH IDENTITY = 'Managed Service Identity';

#create External Data Source for connection
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE ext_datasource_with_abfss WITH (TYPE = hadoop, 
LOCATION = 'abfss://myfile@mystorageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net', 
CREDENTIAL = msi_cred);
```

**Reference:**[Use virtual network service endpoints and rules for servers in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/vnet-service-endpoint-rule-overview?toc=%2Fazure%2Fsql-data-warehouse%2Ftoc.json&view=azuresql)

Comment: Please note that I have my SQL server and storage account in different tenants. In this case, I will not be able to assign the managed identity of SQL server access to Storage Account as Blob Data Contributor. This is the issue.