# terraform initialisation from GitHub workflow

Tags: terraform, github-actions, terraform-provider-azure

I have a repo in which I have terraform infrastructure declared. I'm changing it by moving repeatable parts to modules and created folders for each environment. GitHub workflow is running init, plan and apply. As I have created new directories, I'm changing "working-directory" for init part, but I receive error Failed to get existing workspaces containers.Client#ListBlobs: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure:

I have arm access keys declared as envs in workflow. I tried to move it around but no luck. I dont know why terraform can initialise from main directory but can't initialise from child directory.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment:***

I got same error in case of storageaccount itself:

[image]
This error occurs when one doesn’t have access to the backend or the container where the terraform state is stored.

Please make sure that you are logged in to the subscription or tenant where you have access to resources.

In my case I logged in to another subscription that caused the error .

- Set the subscription correctly.
  **`az account set --subscription "xxx"`**
  and then run terraform init
  To reconfigure for new working directory :
  Run **`terraform init -reconfigure`**

Or run below command to migratethe state:
**`terraform init -migrate-state`**

```
terraform {
  backend "azurerm" {
    resource_group_name      = "rg"
    storage_account_name     = "remotestatekavstr"
    container_name           = "terraform"
    key                      = "terraform.tfstate"
  }
}
```

Then the terraform is initialized successfully:

[image]

> **Note:**
> 1.Check for any spelling corrections of the storage account or container .
>
> 2.When changed to new directory , reconfigure the terraform backend or migrate .

Also check this [creating-azure-storage-containers-in-a-storage-account-with-network-rules-with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71022815/creating-azure-storage-containers-in-a-storage-account-with-network-rules-with)